# How to communicate with an Android device through USB type C using P-NUCLEO-USB002?

Tags: android, usb, stm32, stm32f0

We are students in second year of the engineering cycle at ECE Paris, Lyon, a general engineering school in Paris. As part of our annual enhanced project, we are currently working on a project that aims to reduce the degradation of a smartphone's battery. If you are interested, feel free to look at the presentation of our concept.

https://docs.google.com/presentation/d/16K5bK914NotrKLLLOuzBLQY73Q2vPNgH9Ro1W5MMYjI/edit?usp=sharing

Our prototype would be based on a Lithium-Titanate battery and the **P-NUCLEO-USB002 kit** in order to take advantage of the capabilities of **USB type-C** such as the **Power Delivery protocol**. Our goal would be to first connect an Android smartphone to the development board via a USB type-C cable and implement the **Android Open Accessory Protocol 2.0**. The application on the smartphone would allow the user to select the charging speed. The choice would be sent to the microcontroller which, through the Power Delivery protocol, could adapt the load.

However, we have great difficulties in finding information on how to implement the various protocols. We have downloaded various software such as: STM32CubeMX, Atollic TrueStudio for STM32, STMStudio and STM32 ST-LINK Utility. Are there other software to be purchased or other more suitable software?

Could someone help us by providing some resources that would make it easier for us to set up a communication between Android and the kit mentioned above ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `We have downloaded various software such as: STM32CubeMX, Atollic TrueStudio for STM32, STMStudio and STM32 ST-LINK Utility. Are there other software to be purchased or other more suitable software?` Start from the knowldge - read books, learn about USB etc etc. You need to understand how the USB works (descriptors , endpoinds, pipes, interfaces, classes etc etc) When you understand how everything works start downloading the IDEs.

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to use my Stm32 lib(for activation) and USB class for bulk communication.
Lib works on tom of HAL(CubeMX)

https://github.com/once2go/Stm32-Android-Accessory